# Animate image along path to a specified position using CAKeyFrameAnimation

Tags: ios

What I am trying to achieve is being able to animate and position an image along a path at a specified location along the path.  A percentage along the path would be fine.

What I want to achieve:

[image: Current Location of Image Along the Path]
[image: New position long the path]

What happens is that when I set the animation, it animates across the entire path, back to the starting point.  I need to know how to specify a stopping point anywhere along the path.

Snippet follows:

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"EMOTICON_0.png"]];
[view addSubview:imageView];

CAKeyframeAnimation *positionAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
positionAnimation.path = [view path].CGPath;
positionAnimation.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto;
positionAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
positionAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
positionAnimation.duration = 5.0;
positionAnimation.timingFunction =  [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];


[imageView.layer addAnimation:positionAnimation forKey:positionAnimation.keyPath];
```

Comment: Not solving your question but you should be using `kCAAnimationPaced` instead of `@"paced"`. Those constants are defined for a reason.

Comment: maybe this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464974/cakeyframeanimation-manual-progress/17465640#17465640) can help you

Comment: when you want to stop the animation you could get the imageView.layer.presentationLayer.position and then stop the animation, and then set the imageView's frame to reflect the new position.